# Kafka connect elastic search ID creation for multiple fields not working

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am asking this question as there was no answer in the original case: [Elastic Kafka Connector, ID Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732762/elastic-kafka-connector-id-creation).

I have a similar situation.

Elastic search table to create a record for a single field, but not for multiple fields when request sent through kafkaconnect.

Getting exception **"Key is used as document id and can not be null"** in elastic search.

**My Connector Configurations:**

```
{
 "name": "test-connector33",
 "config": {
 "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
 "tasks.max": "1",
 "topics": "test-connector33",
 "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
 "type.name": "aggregator",
 "schema.ignore": "true",
 "topic.schema.ignore": "true",
  "topic.key.ignore": "false",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
 "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
 "key.ignore":"false",
 "name": "test-connector33",
"transforms": "InsertKey,extractKey",
"transforms.InsertKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.InsertKey.fields":"customerId,city",
"transforms.extractKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
"transforms.extractKey.field":"customerId,city"
}}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am submitting the below data to topic:    echo "{   \"customerId\" : \"Jishnu1534465795885\", \"city\" : \"fremont\",  \"name\" : \"Jishnu\",   \"age\" : 31,   \"address\" : [ {     \"addressId\" : \"21534465795884\",     \"city\" : \"Dallas\",     \"state\" : \"TX\"   }, {     \"addressId\" : \"11534465795884\",     \"city\" : \"Detroit\",     \"state\" : \"MI\"   } ] }"| ./kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-connector33

Comment: @rmoff, any idea how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key` only supports single fields.

Pretend your JSON object was a `HashMap<String, Object>`. You cannot find the field `customerId,city`, and so that `map.get(field)` operation returns `null`, therefore setting the field to be null.

If you want to send keys via the console producer, you are welcome to do that by adding `--property print.key=true` as a flag, then typing the key, press tab, then putting the value. If you want to echo data into the process, then you can also set `--property key.separator='|'`, for a vertical bar as well as add `--property parse.key=true`